# R or Java: Is there a package to convert zip codes to latitude and longitude and put on a map?

Tags: java, r, geolocation

Is there any package or combination of packages that can take a list of zip codes and:

1) Convert them to latitudes and longitudes

2) Put the points on a map

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `install.packages("zipcode")` from CRAN to get this information in R.  This provides a `data(zipcode)` attachment which is a data.frame with the information you need.

With regards to plotting the zip code information on the map, use the `map` package and the spatial routines package `sp`.  Here is an example.

```
## Preliminary
library(maps)
library(zipcode)
library(sp)
data(zipcode)

## Plot state map of USA
map("state")

## Select locations for 100 random zip codes
plotZip <- zipcode[sample(nrow(zipcode))[1:100], c("longitude", "latitude")]

## Plot them
plot(SpatialPoints(plotZip[complete.cases(plotZip),]), pch=20, cex=0.75, add=TRUE, col="red")
```

[image: 100 random zipcodes in the USA]

To select a list of zipcodes for plotting subset `zipcode` giving a vector of the zipcodes required.  Then recreate `plotZip`:

```
plotZip <- subset(zipcode, 
   subset=(zip %in% c(90210, 90211)), 
   select=c("longitude", "latitude"))
```

Comment: Wow! Is there an equivalent for Canada?

Comment: Does it work for other countries than the US? I'm interested on getting an equivalent solution for European countries (preferably Spain and France).

Answer (score 4):

Try: http://www.geonames.org/postal-codes/

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little late to the game here, but I've written an in-memory postal code database API in Java, called [QuickGeo](https://github.com/kickroot/quickgeo). It won't map items, but it does zip->lat/lon lookups very quickly.  To query the lat/lon of a Seattle zip code:

```
PostalDb db = PostalDbFactory.getPostalDb();
Place p = db.byPostalCode("98177").get(0);
double lat = p.getLatitude();
double lon = p.getLongitude();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a website that does it for you here:
[GPS Visualizer](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/geocoder/).